# laravel 5.5 FormRequest class is redirecting to me i need send array errors response

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-request, laravel-5.5, laravel-response

I have a problem when i **validate a request** with a *FormRequest* extended class. **Because is redirecting** when a bad request is recived and **i need a response with the validation errors**.

I'm using:

- **PHP 7.1.1** (cli) (built: Jan 18 2017 18:51:14) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 )
  Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies.
- **Laravel v5.5.2**.

**My FormRequest class:**

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class BillRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'testfield' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\BillRequest;
use App\Bill;

class BillController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(BillRequest $request)
    {
        $bills = Bill::paginate(10);
        return $bills;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(BillRequest $request)
    {
        $bill = new Bill($request->all());
        $bill->save();
        return response('', 201);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $bill = Bill::find($id);
        $bill->customer->person;
        $bill->vehicle;
        $bill->items;
        return response($bill, 200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(BillRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $bill = Bill::find($id);
        $bill->fill($request->all());
        $bill->save();
        return response('', 200);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $bill = Bill::find($id);
        $bill->delete();
        return response('', 204);
    }
}
```

**Route (api.php):**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin' ], function () {
    Route::resource('bills', 'BillController', [
        'only' => ['index', 'update', 'show']
    ]);
});
```

Finally, the response with the field 'testfield' (in the request) is the JSON with the data paginated. But when i send the request without the field then redirect to *localhost:8000/*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem. It's for a missing header in the request.

```
Content-Type:application/json
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: it is weird, only when using FormRequest inherited requests in the api endpoints it will redirect to home page unless you add both of these two headers.

Comment: Yes, it is weird.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem using Laravel 5.5.3

There are many people who recommend to overwrite the *response* method in the custom *FormRequest* class, anyway this doesn't seem to work any longer since the method *failedValidation* is called before. This method throws an *Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException*.

You can catch this exception in *app/Exceptions/Handler.php*

Comment: Hi. Can you please share some more information on this?

Answer (score -3):

To validate json in Laravel, check Laravel documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#available-validation-rules